# Firebase Cloud Firestore rules / permissions issue

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to set permissions so a user with a given email address can only read a document with a matching docId.

This is the collection of documents:

```
/cats/a@test.com
/cats/b@test.com
/cats/c@test.com
```

The following works perfectly in the "Rules Playground", but it always ends up returning nothing in my Angular app.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /cats/{catDocId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.email.lower() == catDocId;
      allow write: if false;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is the app code:

**myPage.component.ts:**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// ...

cats: Observable<any[]>;

// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        this.cats = this.firestore.collection('cats').valueChanges();
    });
}
```

**myPage.component.html:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="text" *ngFor="let cat of cats | async">
        {{cat.name}}, {{cat.color}}, {{cat.favoriteFood}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas where this is going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Obvious question: Is your user logged in?

Comment: Also, can you share your query? It is indeed important to note that security rules are not filters, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Yes, the user's logged in, and I've edited the question to include the Angular code. Thanks

Comment: So it seems I'm trying to use the rules as a filter.  Is there a simple way to grant read access to a single doc based on the user's token data, namely their email address?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> So it seems I'm trying to use the rules as a filter. Is there a simple
> way to grant read access to a single doc based on the user's token
> data, namely their email address?

You just need to use the [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object in order to get the user's email. I'm not really versed in `angularfire` but the following code (from the angularfire [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) on Authentication) shows how to get the `displayName` property. You should do the same with the `email` property. Then you should directly query the document, as explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md), since you have the entire [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
      <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
      <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #showLogin>
      <p>Please login.</p>
      <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud.  I can look up the user's email with no problem.  Does that mean I should set my Cloud Firestore permissions to "allow read: if request.auth != null;"  (ie: allow a read if the user is logged in) and then filter the results on the Angular side? I'm just trying to be as secure as possible in the Firebase database

Comment: `allow read: if request.auth.token.email.lower() == catDocId;` is necessary (it prevents other users to read the user's doc) and it is also sufficient IMO, since `request.auth` will be null if the user is not logged in.

Comment: So to be complete, no need to " filter the results on the Angular side". Just fetch **one and only one doc**, the doc with the `/cats/a@test.com` path and secure it as you do in your question.

Comment: But the problem remains that `allow read: if request.auth.token.email.lower() == catDocId;` only works in the Rules Playground, and it returns zero docs in the actual Angular app :(

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly fetching one doc. You should not [query the collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) but [fetch one specific doc based on its path/reference](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md).

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was it! I have to query for the document instead of retrieving the collection of docs!

Comment: You could query the collection but you would need to filter the query based on the user's email (with `where()`), in order to query the exact doc (the rule will not filter the query, the query must corresponds to the rule). Since you are looking for ONE doc, it is more logical to directly fetch this doc. Please accept the answer as well if it solved your problem. Thanks.